# Larave, vue You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: laravel, webpack, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I'm using Larave 5.5.* and with laravel mix v6.0.19.
Previously I had installed laravel mix v2.1.14 and upgraded to the laravel mix v6.0.19.

When I run `npm run watch-poll` I get the following error.
[image]

How do I remove this error ?

**Update**
My `webpack.mix.js`:

```js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue({ version: 2 });
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .version();
```

I've removed other error. Now there is only one error. It seems like laravel-mix cannot compile JSX code.The error is coming from component of `elements-ui`

Package.json

[Link](https://pastebin.com/7kwfWYLQ)

.babelrc

[Link](https://pastebin.com/kPTVCU8b)

Comment: Upgrading Mix versions may result in breaking changes.  Did you review the appropriate upgrade guides to make sure everything is compatible with Mix 6?  https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/upgrade  Your jump from Mix 2 to Mix 6 is not insignificant and may involve additional changes not discussed in the linked guide.  If you post your `webpack.mix.js` file, perhaps we may be able to provide further advice.

Comment: @matticustard question updated.

Comment: Thanks. I'll admit, that was less helpful than I expected. Everything looks okay. Does your Vue require look like this? (note **.default**)  `window.Vue = require('vue').default;`

Comment: No, It is in this form `window.Vue = require('vue');`

Comment: Did you try it with `.default` added?

Comment: Also, can you please add your `package.json` file to the post?

Comment: I've updated the question. It seems like laravel mix is having issue compiling jsx